# Proof: centers of circle tangent to circle and line lies on parabola

Tags: geometry

first please take a look at this:[image]

Given was a circle $c$ with center $A$ and ratio $r$, furthermore three lines $g$, $g1$, $g2$ with:

- $r = d(g, g1) = d(g, g2)$.
- Finally, two parabolas $p1$ (and $p2$) are being constructed through $A$ and $g1$ (and $g2$).

I'd like to show now, that the center $G$ of a circle touching both $g$ and the circle around A ($c$ in the picture) lies on the parabola p1 (or p2, if A is on the side of g1 and not on the same side as g2 as in the picture). Int he picture the circle around G does not fulfill the demands, but when its ratio is widened it will.

So my aim is to show that:

- $|AG|=|Gg1|$ (per definition of parabola)

But shouldn't this be quite obvious since with $r_A$ (ratio around A) and $r_G$ (ratio around G):  $|AG|=r_A + r_G = |Gg1|$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that "ratio" in the question means "radius".

> So my aim is to show that:
>
> - $|AG|=|Gg1|$ (per definition of parabola)
>
> But shouldn't this be quite obvious since with $r_A$ (ratio around A) and $r_G$ (ratio around G):  $|AG|=r_A + r_G = |Gg1|$ ?

It is obvious :

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

First, we have
$$|AG|=r_A+r_G$$
since the two circles are touching with each other.

Also,
$$|Gg_1|=|Gg|+|gg_1|=r_G+r=r_G+r_A$$
since the cirlce whose center is $G$ is touching $g$ with $r_A=r$.

It follows from these that $|AG|=|Gg_1|$.

As you wrote, by the definition of parabola, we can say that the center $G$ of a circle touching both $g$ and the circle $c$ lies on the parabola $p_1$ (or $p_2$ if $A$ is on the side of $g_1$ and not on the same side as $g_2$).